# Don't understand solution to proving f(x) = 1/x is continuous at x = 1/2

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

WHen it says "However, the graph of $| \frac{2}{x}|$ makes it clear that ... " THis sentence, can someone explain why $\delta$ has to be less that 1/2?

Comment: If $\delta\geq 1/2$ then you can choose $x$  arbitrarily close to $0$ and therefore $|2/x|$ will be arbitrarily large.

Comment: one more thing, where does the choosing C = 8 come from? If I play with the delta restriction on the x, wouldn't the reasonable C = 8/3? (from ||<3/4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that you want $|2/x| < C$ for all $x$ satisfying $0 < |x-\frac{1}{2}| < \delta$.

If $\delta \ge 1/2$, then $x$ can be arbitrarily close to zero (e.g., $x=0.01$ or $x=0.0001$) and still satisfy the constraint $|x - \frac{1}{2}| < \delta$. But then $|2/x|$ will be arbitrarily large.

Comment: one more thing, where does the choosing C = 8 come from? If I play with the delta restriction on the x, wouldn't the reasonable C = 8/3? (from $|x| < 3/4$)

Comment: @MinYoungKim When $|x-1/2| \le 1/4$ we have $x \ge 1/4$ so $|2/x| \le 2/(1/4) = 8$.